# Using jQuery to reference Ext JS Components

Tags: jquery, extjs, components, element

So I have this jQuery plugin which is a popup tour that iterates through HTML DOM elements. It's up and working, and is implemented like this:

```
$(function () {
        options = {
            data : [
              { element: '#container', 'tooltip' : 'Welcome to the MetaCenter Web Application!' },
```

The element is called either through a an element's ID, class or actual element (ui, li, body, etc..).

Is there any way to configure this to Ext JS components? (comboboxes, textfields)

Cheers mates!

Answer (score 0):

Ext components are all composed of actual HTML elements, and the topmost element always have an id.

With a reference to your component, you can get its id with the [`getId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getId) method.

Or you can approach the problem in the other way, and configure a known [`id`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-id) for your components, then use it in your jQuery code.

Comment: I gave my components an id and called them with the jquery function, but some of them are either not on the component at all, or way off to the side.

Comment: Is there a z-index or something I should give them?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell. I would need to see all that running to get a clue what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/08/extjs-jquery-together-same.html

You can use the .el.dom properties to get a reference to an item:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var f = new MyPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    var referenceToImage = f.down('image').el.dom;

    $(referenceToImage).Jcrop();

});
```